# Runtime boolean and String error in java?

Tags: java

Hi that println giving me error but it working fine if I just print them separately. Any Idea why this happening?

```
 class StringTesting
{
public static void main(String me[])
{
    String s1="Varun";
    String s2="varun";
    String s3="Varun";
    String s4=new String("Varun");
    String s5=new String("Varun");
    System.out.println(" "+s1==s3+" "+s1==s2+" ");//here its giving me error
}
}
```

And also thanks in Advance :)

Comment: `==` doesn't have the precedence you seem to be expecting from it.

Comment: (assuming you're expecting the precedence to work out to `" "+(s1==s3)+" "+(s1==s2)+" "`)

Comment: Giving you *what* error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), `+` has the precedence on `==`.

It means that this code :

```
" "+s1==s3+" "+s1==s2+" "
```

is translated by the compiler by something like that :

```
" Varun"=="Varun Varun"=="Varun "
```

the first part `" Varun"=="Varun Varun"`  produces a `boolean`

and applying to it the `"Varun " String` with the `==` comparator, it results to :

```
booleanExpression == "Varun "
```

Comparing `boolean` with a `String` is not valid.
Anyway, even if it was, you don't want to as you want to output the boolean result of the `==` comparison between the objects.

So just put between parentheses the `==` comparisons to indicate to the compiler that operations in have to be evaluated together :

```
" "+(s1==s3)+" "+(s1==s2)+" "
```

It will produce a valid concatenation :

`String` + `boolean` + `String` + `boolean` + `String`

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare booleans and strings using `==` and this is what is indeed happening there because of **the order of operators being applied**.

You can fix that using simple brackets:

```
System.out.println(" " + (s1 == s3) + " " + (s1 == s2) + " ");
```

Of course, if you do not combine results of two different operators, that will work just fine:

```
System.out.println(s1 == s3);
```

So, it was enough to just read the compilation error.

Comment: but it working fine when I am doing this System.out.println(s1==s3);

Comment: @VARUNSINGH because there is only one operator - the problem is when you try to combine `+` and `==` because of the operator precedence

Comment: @VARUNSINGH I am glad to help :) please upvote and accept if it solved your problem

Comment: well actually this answer didnt solve my problem but your comment did, but anyway

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java documentation on String, the proper way to compare two strings is by using the .equals method.

```
System.out.println("s1 == s2 ?: " + s1.equals(s2))
```

By using the == operator between two Objects you are comparing memory locations, not the actual primitive value(s) contained in the object.

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely misinterpreted the question. I have tried to delete this answer as it is not relevant but apparently the phone app doesn't have that button.

Comment: so whats you waiting for?

Comment: The missing delete button to appear in the app.

Comment: but it working fine when I am doing this System.out.println(s1==s3);